# Group by custom list linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have problem in understanding custom group by and order by. Here is the scenario,

I have an object contain data.

Objects->object->name; (structure of the object)

and i want to group by custom list that i have (name is the key object for grouping).

name is like a,b,c and i want b,c,a(sample).

Here is my work around

```
IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Snit>> assetGrouping = sUnits.ToArray().GroupBy(e => e.Name).OrderBy(e => e.Key);
```

and i want to group and order by my custom list

```
List<string > customOrder=new List<string>();
            customOrder.Add("any");
customOrder.Add("some");
```

can any body help me..

Comment: What if there is a name which will be not contained in your custom order list?

Comment: @MBudnik Then it will be moved last. I want only the listed item will be first, others will be last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I scrapped using LINQPad:

Prerequisites:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

var keys = new[]{"1", "15", "13", "16"};

var random = new Random();

var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
    .Select( _ => new Data
    {
        Name = random.Next(24).ToString()
    });

var keys = new[]{"1", "15", "13", "16"};
```

Now, the grouping:

```
var grouped = data.GroupBy(x => keys.FirstOrDefault(k=>k==x.Name));
```

The query above will group the items in `data` as following: for each value `x` in `data`, if there is a key `k` in `keys` with `k == x.Name`, the value will be added to a separate group having the key `k`; all the other values will be added to a separate group having the key `null`;

For the ordering of the groups you just need to use the position of each group key in the `keys` array.

```
var ordered = grouped.OrderBy( g =>
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(keys, g.Key);
    return index == -1 ? int.MaxValue : index;
});
```

`Array.IndexOf` will return `-1` if the item wasn't found in the dictionary. In this case, according to your needs, the item must be at the end of the collection so return max value. Otherwise, just use the index of the key.

The results are in the image below:
[image: Query results.]